# $('.small').css('width',$(this).siblings('.large').css('width'));

Tags: jquery, html

I have two type of different div : some are small and some are large.

I would like the small ones to have the same width than the large ones.

It seems I can't use `$(this)` inside a `.css` attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gs2kD/12/

Comment: your fiddle has the same size images, and you can use it but im assuming `$(this)` is not referring to anything. It certainly is not referring to `$(".small")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jQuery instead of mootools.

And you need to define a callback function along with `css()`

This will probably look like this:

```
$('.small').css('width',function(){ 
    return $(this).siblings('.large').css('width'); 
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gs2kD/14/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Gs2kD/15/

```
$('.small').each(function(){
   $(this).css('width', $(this).siblings('.large').width());
});
```